# Custom Exceptions Class Naming in Java

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

I am trying to create a custom exception class but having trouble naming. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
     public MyException() {
     }
}
```

Now, I want an exception that is not called `MyException`. Can I use:

```
public void EmptyException() {
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes ofcourse, just do the same thing again :)
create a new class called EmptyException

in same class:

```
    public class EmptyException extends Exception {
         public EmptyException() {
         }
        public class InnerException extends Exception { //Inner class
           public InnerException() {
               }

          }
    }
```

Comment: @isal A custom exception is simply a class which extends `Exception`. All the rules that apply to classes in general when it comes to location in a file apply to custom exceptions just as well. As an alternative to the inner class in this answer, you can have a non-public top-level exception class.

Comment: Although possible, why would you want to create an exception as an inner class of another exception? Looks like a code smell to me.

Comment: @assylias I have about 4 exceptions that are reused through out the program. I just felt having 4 different classes with one method in each would be mundane. Maybe I'm wrong, but that was my thinking.

Comment: Yup.  Classes are cheap; if you're using them throughout the program, then making them their own classes is totally the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer creating one exception per file:

Within **MyException.java**:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    //useless to define here the default constructor
}
```

Within **EmptyException.java**

```
public class EmptyException extends Exception {
    //useless to define here the default constructor
}
```

In this case, using inner-classes = **code smell**.

If both exceptions are really linked together, prefer inheritance over inner-classing:

```
public class EmptyException extends MyException {
  //useless to define here the default constructor since parent's constructor is zero-arg one.
}
```